# Laravel: llenar un select con valores de tablas con llave foranea

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

estoy teniendo algunos problemas al generar campos select con datos en mi bd, el escenario es el siguiente:
Tengo 5 tablas:

- **carro_compra:** id, nombre, descripcion,precio_total
- **bebidas_carro:** id,bebidas_id,carro_compra_id(foranea)
- **productos_extra_carro:** id, productos_extra_id(foranea),carro_compra_id(foranea)
- **bebidas:** id,nombre,precio
- **productos_extra:** id,nombre,precio,proveedor_id(foranea)

Esto lo agrego en un formulario en el que agrego varios campos select mediante jquery con los datos de las dos tablas **bebidas y productos_extra**, y los datos seleccionados se guardan en las tablas **bebidas_carro y productos_extra_carro** respectivamente, el agregar me funciona perfecto pero al editar necesito generar los campos select que se han guardado previamente de las tablas **bebidas_carro y productos_extra_carro** mas los datos de mis tablas  **bebidas y productos_extra** para poder cambiar si se desea, como podria generar estos select? estoy empezando con Laravel y esto me esta dando vueltas la cabeza.. alguna idea? gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Hola @maudev, ¡bienvenido a [es.so]! Es un tanto abstracto intentar ayudarte sin ver el código que intentaste hasta ahora. ¿Podrías incluir lo mínimo indispensable de tu código para entender en qué estás teniendo problemas? Por favor lee [mcve] (Ayudanos a ayudarte! :)

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, codigo no puedo poner porque aca es donde me quede estancado, tengo entendido que para hacer el populate de un select se hace mediante $bebidas = Bebida::lists('nombre','id'); y "magicamente" al editar se hace un "selected" la opcion que esta guardada en la tabla

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacer esto para una tabla diferente, que tambien depende de la tabla Bebida, que es mi tabla bebidas_carro, en esta tabla guardo un registro Bebida y lo que necesito es que al editar se muestre esta y los demas registros bebidas por si se desea cambiar, aca el metodo lists no me sirve porq me carga todas las bebidas no asi la seleccionada..

Comment: Qué modelos tienes actualmente? Por lo que veo se necesitan tres: CarroCompra, Bebidas y ProductosExtra.

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo que explicas debes de tener 3 modelos:
BebidaCarro, Bebida y CarroCompra

Donde BebidaCarro hereda las PK de bebida(bebida_id) y de carrocompra(carro_compra_id) estas llaves foraneas deben de estar definidas en tus migraciones como tal.

**Luego en tu model BebidaCarro:**

```
public function bebidas(){
 return 
$this>belongsTo(
'App\Bebida','bebidas_id')
}

public function 
carro_compra(){
 return 
 $this>belongsTo(
 'App\CarroCompra',
 'carro_compra_id')
}
```

**Luego en tu controlador:**

```
public function 
 formulario(){
 $bebidas_carro = 
 Bebidas_Carro:   
 :with('bebidas',
 'carro_compra')->get(); 
 //algo general...

 //enviamos los datos a la vista
 return view('tuvista', 
 compact(
 '$bebidas_carro'));
  }
```

**Luego en tu vista:**

por ejemplo si en este formulario quieres mostrar los nombres de las bebidas

```
<select>
 @foreach($bebidas_carro as $bc)
   <option value="$bc->bebidas->id"> {{ $bc->bebidas->nombre }} </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar en algo.